# Algorithm for enumerating all the faces of a multigraph with given planar embedding

Tags: graph-theory

I am looking for an algorithm that enumerates all the faces of an unordered planar multigraph with a given planar embedding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start, tag all the vertices with the letter $V$ to indicate that they are vertices of the original graph.

Now place two new vertices on every edge, every edge separates two faces. We are going to use tags on this vertices to keep track of the found faces.This new vertices are only for tagging purposes, when we talk about edges in the following steps we will be referring to the original ones. We will call the new vertices "tvertices"

[image]

Select a vertex tagged with $V$ and one of its edges. Tag the closest tvertex from the selected vertex with a $1$ to indicate that this one has been used for the first face.

[image]

From the selected vertex, swipe the selected edge clockwise until it meets another edge that emanates from the selected vertex. We select that edge and the other vertex that defines that edge. We now tag the tvertex of the new selected edge closest to the new selected vertex.

[image]

Continue swiping, reselecting and tagging until you get to the original vertex. The set of vertices and edges you had selected define a face.

[image]

Select now a vertex and one of its edges with the condition that the tvertex of said edge closest to the selected vertex has not been tagged yet. Repeat the same process to find a new face but now tagging the tvertices with $2$. Continue until all the tvertices have been tagged, changing the tag to $n+1$ once the $n$-th face has been found.

All the faces have been found exactly once (this includes the exterior face).

[image]

Comment: Although the example is not a multigraph, this algorighm works even if you have multiple edges between two vertices. If you have edges that start and end in the same vertex (loops), you can place a "fake" vertex that divides said edge in two and then apply the above algorithm.

Comment: Looks good, thank you.

Comment: But I think, you don't have to walk in two directions, you just always have to select the rightmost edge starting from a vertex. And the explanation is not entirely correct, since in the first case the 3rd selected vertex would be a vertex on the outer face and not the one you marked (if we follow the clockwise order.) But the idea behind it is OK, and it works.

Comment: Edit: my fault, the explanation is correct.

Comment: Is it possible to distinguish the outer face from the others?

Comment: If the planar embedding has straight edges, you could measure the swiped angles and count the number of sides. If you sum all the swiped angles you should get $180(n-2)$ degrees for the inner faces and $180(n+2)$ degrees for the outer one (where $n$ is the number of sides). Note that a graph with multiple edges between two vertices cannot have a straight edge embedding.

Comment: You could also construct a horizontal line through every vertex. It will intersect several points of the graph (edges and/or vertices). The rightmost and leftmost points belong to edges and/or vertices that define the outer face. If the set of points that result from the first line are shared by two faces you cannot decide wich one is the outer one yet. Proceed with a second horizontal line and continue until one of them yields a point that belongs to one of the first two faces but not the other one. Note that this does not work if you only have one inner face.

Comment: The last method might work better if you construct the lines through edges instead of vertices. This removes some special cases where the method does not work.